# Shapely problems within conda environment

Tags: polygon, shapely, conda

I was, so far, using Shapely to work with polygon data to "filter" some point within the polygon. I have tried to define a polygon like this.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

poly_sipesipe = [(-66.378119011,-17.423363001), 
                 (-66.287410692,-17.431080602), 
                 (-66.287111378,-17.571962784),
                 (-66.388352182,-17.562721095),
                 (-66.378119011,-17.423363001)]

polygon = Polygon(poly_sipesipe)
```

However, I obtained this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Main thread:
Current thread 0x00007fa926674740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/asus/anaconda3/envs/pygmt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 539 in geos_polygon_from_py
  File "/home/asus/anaconda3/envs/pygmt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 261 in __init__
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_23437/2515029701.py", line 1 in <cell line: 1>
```

My conda version is 22.9.0, I am Ubuntu 20.0 LTS user.

Does anyone have this error?

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/383

Comment: Works for me with shapely 1.8.5 and 2.0.1 (both from conda-forge), Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @user2856, worked upgrading Shapely to 2.0.1